# Programmatically assigning datasource to UITableView not calling datasource method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

I have `tableview` with two section each with one row.
I want to fill `tableview` data on button click.
In `viewDidLoad` I am hiding `tableView`.
On button click I assigning `datasource` and `delegate` to `tableview` and unhiding the `tableview` but its `datasource` methods are not being called.

Below is the code:

```
@IBAction func btnShowAction(_ sender: Any) {

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.isHidden = false
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return ((tableView.frame.size.height / 2) - 20)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if(section == 0) {

        return "Section 1"
    }
    else {

        return "Section 2"
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    tableViewCell.lblText.text = "abc"
    return tableViewCell
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting your data source and delegate in button action?

Comment: I want to fill data in tableview as per user request if needed

Comment: Chetan, You need to reload your tableview, If you want to show your updated data to TableView

Comment: That doesn't justify it.

Comment: @abdul it does not automatically reloads data as I am setting datasource?

Comment: @chetanpanchal How? You have to inform your tableview delegate that, your Data is updated and also need to update your tableview. It won't update itself. Just  try yourself and check it. Its gonna work.

Comment: @abdul I have tried it is working, but if set datasource in viewDidLoad it automatically calls its datasource method?

Comment: Yes, I think while you view loads that time data source method will call reloadData internally, but not in case of button click, in that case, we need to call reloadData explicitly

Comment: @bappaditya I think you are right we need to explicitly call the reloadData method, it may call implicitly if we set in viewDidload.

Answer (score 0):

While the view loads e.g `viewDidLoad()` that time data source method will call `reloadData()` internally, but in your case on button click, we need to call `reloadData()` explicitly to update the table view as the view is already loaded. Your code should look like this,

```
@IBAction func btnShowAction(_ sender: Any) {

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.isHidden = false
}
```

This reloads the rows and sections of the table view. Hope it helps.

Comment: why do I need to tableView.reloadData()?

Comment: reloadData() method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers, and footers, index arrays.

You may want to refer, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

Comment: it does not automatically reloads rows of a section after setting datasource

Comment: As per Apple's documentation, the table view’s delegate or data source calls `reloadData` method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data

Comment: `tableView.dataSource = self` does the initial load of the data. you don't need to call reload straight after setting it. use reload when the data has changed